# register windows registry file using inno setup

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

Have no programming language experience. Can someone help me create this windows registry file for 64 bit os, using inno.

I have a

> register_me.reg

which looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\kiv]
@="KivURI"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\kiv\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\kiv\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\kiv\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Documents\\MyApp\\kiv\\exec.bat %1"
```

Looking at [this](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) documentation I could only figure out how to start:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "C:\Documents\MyApp\kiv\exec.bat %1"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

Any tip on how to start will be appreciated. Thanks a ton

Comment: Also note that some Inno IDEs have the ability to import a reg file and create the associated `[Registry]` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add keys one by one like below:

```
 [Registry]
    Root: HKCR; Subkey: "kiv"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: none; 
    Root: HKCR; Subkey: "kiv"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "URL Protocol"; ValueData: "";
    Root: HKCR; Subkey: "kiv\shell"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: none
    Root: HKCR; Subkey: "kiv\shell\open"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: none
    Root: HKCR; Subkey: "kiv\shell\open\command"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "C:\Documents\MyApp\kiv\exec.bat %1";
```

Hope it helped!